# Enterprise developer iPad App crash on launch

Tags: ios, logging, crash, launch

I've an enterprise app that crash on launch. (suddenly, without any update of the iOS operative system or of the app itself)

I cannot access the iPad because it's physically far from me.

I try to guide the user to send me the log that i find under Settings -> Privacy -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostic & Usage Data but it seems that all the log refer to last year.

How can I understand what is going on? Is there a way to see what happens on the device's console from remote?

I don't think it's a certificate issue because all my certificate (provisioning profile, distribution profile and subscription to the enterprise development program) are ok.

Comment: you should have implemented some logging framework like crashlytics or test flight.

Comment: Do you use any third party libraries or code that might be deprecated ?

Comment: I use a third party library but on other iPad is still working...and i expect that if the problem is a third party libraries will stop working when I update the OS, but when I try (when exit 8.1.2 ) all worked fine.

Comment: Even you mentioned your certificate looks fine, but I think the certificate you used to build the same app might have expired previously. Though you have updated it, you might have forgotten to build it with a new updated certificate.